# Is it okay to assign an instantiated class to a class variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it okay to instantiate a class A and assign it to a class variable in class B to call A's methods in B?

```
class A
  ...
end

class B
  @@a = A.new

  def method_B
    @@a.method_A
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK. Are you encountering an error or unexpected results?

Comment: @lurker No, I just saw that people usually do something like that: `def initialize @a = A.new`, so I was not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: It's right *if* what you want is a *class* variable. `@@a = A.new` sets a *class* variable for the class `B`. `@a = A.new` sets an *instance* variable. How you plan to use it is what matters. Do you know the difference between *class* and *instance* variables?

Comment: I know the difference but I don't have much experience. I'm just going to use A's methods in class B to kind of extend its functionality without writing the same methods again.

Comment: I see. That's probably not the best way to structure that commonality. You might want to lookup "mixins" and "modules" in Ruby (just Google "ruby mixins" and you'll find a bunch of information, including tutorials like [this one](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/)).

Comment: There is almost never a right time to use class variables. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap methods in a module and `include` them in your class(For instance methods only)

```
module Foo
  def method_A
    p 'hello'
  end
end

class B
  include Foo
  def method_B
    method_A
  end
end

B.new.method_B
```